# How to click post button in Facebook groups?, webdriver Java

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, post, webdriver

I also cannot click this button with the below code, i've tried:

```
    driver.navigate().to(groupname);
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    driver.findElement(By.name("xhpc_message_text")).sendKeys(LinkYT+"\n");
    Thread.sleep(3000); 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\button\\span[.=\"Post\"]")).click();
```

I've used also waits and cssSelectors but cannot manage to click the button. I'm surely doing something wrong

Do you you have a suggestion?

```
<button class="_1mf7 _4jy0 _4jy3 _4jy1 _51sy selected _42ft" data-
testid="react-composer-post-button" type="submit" value="1"><img alt="" 
class="_3-8_ _5gm4 img" 
src="https://www.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v3/yb/r/GsNJNwuI-UM.gif" data-
testid="react-composer-throbber" width="16" height="11"><span 
class="">Post</span></button>
```

ex for one of my tries, all have same no such element exection. so xpath,css selector etc i get them wrong for this button...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no 
such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@type='submit']
[contains(text(),'Post')]"}
(Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 
(0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 
x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 46 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: 
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'INTERN2017-37', ip: '10.6.220.24', os.name: 'Windows 
10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, 
mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome=
{chromedriverVersion=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41), 
userDataDir=C:\Users\LUCIAN~1.PAT\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir19996_28709}, 
takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, 
handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=61.0.3163.100, 
platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, 
acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, 
browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, 
cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 2bbb3a860bbafbca888b4a9c5af20029
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[@type='submit']
[contains(text(),'Post')]}
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Yes: use the facebook API instead

Comment: i will find one free, as a last resort, i'm stil keen on fixing this right now..

Comment: What’s the use case? You aware that Facebook ToS forbid you from using any such “automation” on their systems?

Comment: used: 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")).click(), and it says Element not Clickable, for .sendKeys("\n"); says unknown error: cannot focus element

Comment: I want to add to 3-4 groups same post for a company, without having to do it manually (no big deal but i wanted to save 15 minutes...)

Answer (score 0):

manged to do it with:

```
  WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    actions.moveToElement(elem).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct but as I guess you can also use xpath using SPAN directly like this

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(elem).click().perform();
```